# Are the treasures on a map randomly allocated?

Tags: blood-brothers

Are the goodies on the map variable for each run-through of a level?  That is, if I repeat a level, will all or some of the treasures change from coffers to piles or money or reliquaries?

Answer (score 1):

Despite my earlier speculation, it appears that most of the coffers, reliquaries, and coins that appear on the map are at least mostly randomly allocated.  Some of the maps contain set features, such as boss locations, and some of this preset behavior may encompass one or two treasures like reliquaries that appear on some branches on some maps.  Other than that, it appears that generally both monsters and treasure are subject to a great deal of randomization.